# Compare Tuple with a List of Tuples

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, tuples, compare

I have to compare a tuple with a list of tuples and returns True if the integers are less than any of the tuples in the list. Like if i have `superM ("Tomato",10,5) [("Potato",5,6),("Orange",11,6)]` will return True because the integers in the alone Tuple ("Tomate",10,5) are smaller then the tuple("Orange",11,6) in the list, but if i have  `superM ("Melon",10,6) [("Potato",5,6),("Orange",11,6)]` will return False.

I try this

```
superM :: (String, Int, Int) -> [(String, Int, Int)] -> Bool
superM (s,a,b) ((_,c,d):xs)
  | a < c && b < d = True
  |otherwise =  superM (s,a,b) xs
```

But doesn't work when it suppose to return False and I don't know why?

Note:The Strings doesn't matter for this problem, i must ignore it.

Comment: You did not define a basecase for the empty list.

Comment: Turning on warnings would report the missing base case. I recommend to always use `-Wall`. (Arguably, it should be on by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define a basecase for the empty list. So if no element matches, eventually the list will be exhausted, and then the empty list will not match. You thus can add a rule for the empty list:

```
superM :: (String, Int, Int) -> [(String, Int, Int)] -> Bool
superM _ [] = False
superM (s,a,b) ((_,c,d):xs)
  | a < c && b < d = True
  |otherwise =  superM (s,a,b) xs
```

we can make use of a logical or to get rid of the guards:

```
superM :: (String, Int, Int) -> [(String, Int, Int)] -> Bool
superM _ [] = False
superM (s,a,b) ((_,c,d):xs) = a < c && b < d || superM (s,a,b) xs
```

but we can also use the [**`any :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) function to let this work with any `Foldable`:

```
superM :: (Foldable f, Ord x, Ord y) => (a, x, y) -> f (b, x, y) -> Bool
superM (_, a, b) = any p
    where p (_, c, d) = a < c && b < d
```